# local images are not displayed, in octopress

Tags: image, github-pages, octopress

I create a post and hope to display some local images, so I put some images in the folder of source/images/my_dir/image.jpg

And then I use the following two ways to display the pictures.

```
![method 1](../images/my_dir/image.jpg)
![method 2](http://my_username.github.io/my_dir/image.jpg)
```

And then I generate the post and deploy to github page.

I can see that the images is copied in the folder of _deploy/images/my_dir/

But method 1 is not working, instead, method 2 is working. Why is that?

PS:I am using windows7 to write the post in markdown pad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your atom.xml all img src must be of the form `![method 2](http://my_username.github.io/my_dir/image.jpg)`. Feeds reader must have resources full urls to display them correctly.

In your post it's `![method 1](/images/my_dir/image.jpg)`

Comment: Would you please explain for the local one, why the path is /images/..... rather than ../images/....., the post is in /posts, while should I need to find images with ../images?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, jekyll is enabled by default and will skip directories that begin with "_". To disable the behaviour, drop an empty file named ".nojekyll" in the root dir.
More info [here](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/)
Yes, it drove me mad too.